# Easy way to extract key-value from hash

Tags: ruby

Is there some nice way to extract key and value from a hash?

My first approach was:

```
a = {:a => :b}
a.keys.first   # => :a
a.values.first # => :b
```

But it looks a bit clumsy, so I came up with this:

```
 k, v = {:a => :b}.to_a.flatten
 k # => :a
 v # => :b
```

Are there some other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
k, v = {a: :b}.first
k # => :a
v # => :b
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two more ways, but I do not think they are nicer than sawa's answer:

```
key, val =  *a.flatten
key, val =  [*a][0]
```

Or, if you do not care about the original hash anymore:

```
key, val =  a.shift
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more, but, the same as hirolau, I don't think it's better than sawa's answer.

`each_pair`, `each` and more methods, returns `Enumerator` object. With this you can get `next` value with... `next`:

```
h.each_pair.next
# [:a, :b]
h.each.next
# => [:a, :b]
```

And `entries` return array of arrays:

```
 a, b = h.entries[0]
```

or other way, using ruby's *pattern matching*:

```
((a,b)) = h.entries
```